# Given the mxn matrix A, show that dimKernA >= n - m.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

So far what I have is the following:

If A is an mxn matrix, it can be represented by the linear mapping F:K^n -> K^m whereby F(A) := Ax for x in K^n. Therefore, by the rank-nullity theorem, we have

dim(ker(A)) + rank(A) = dim(K^n)

which is none other than

dim(ker(A)) + m = n so that

dim(ker(A)) = n - m

What I don't understand now is why dim(ker(A)) is also greater than n - m.

Comment: You replaced "rank(A)" with "m" in your equation. That's incorrect.

Comment: rank(A) <= m, right?

Comment: Yes, rank(A) <= m and rank(A) <= n. But in your equation, you used rank(A) = m, which is not true in general.

Comment: I figured out the solution. Thank you.